# How do I import/add an existing Python file to a PyCharm project?

Tags: python, project, pycharm

How do I import/add an existing Python file to a PyCharm project?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Copy the files to some directory under the project root using your favorite file manager or add the directory containing your files to the project using `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Project Structure` | **Add Content Root**.

Comment: In PyCharm 2020.2, there is no `Settings` menu bar item. It looks like this can now be found under `File` | `Settings` | `Project: <project name>` | `Project Structure` | **Add Content Root**.

Comment: In PyCharm 2021.2, Linux, this setting no longer exists (if it ever did). There is no Project/Project Structure under settings. Things like this are such a frustrating experience with PyCharm that I end up going back to vim or Jupyter-lab for editing. I mean, wouldn't importing code files be one of the most basic usecases? There are tons of useless buttons for things like expanding and contracting the project view but not for adding in files.

Comment: Project structure does appear in Linux version of PyCharm https://i.imgur.com/T1uVr4f.png

Answer (score 29):

I'm not sure if I get what you want, but there's way you can add existing source into project:
File -> Settings -> Project structure -> Add Content root -> choose folder with existing code

Comment: What would happen if I wanted to just include one particular file in the project structure?

Comment: @matt, I have not seen an IDE which does that. Please share if you known of a solution other than copying files or making soft-links or hard-links in os.

Comment: Well, Xcode, for one, does that. This is a difficult to understand Pycharm's limitation. I have been struggling with this issue for too long

Comment: In visual studio you can also import files from anywhere. On build time all the files are copied to your build output folder.

Answer (score 2):

For PyCharm 2017 (v.2017.2.3), it's slightly different.
You still need to copy the files you want to add to a directory under the project's own root directory, but they don't appear in the Project navigation window in PyCharm immediately.
To correct this, click on the Project's name in the Navigation window to collapse the project's tree structure, then open it up again. You should now be able to see the files you've just added.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked this way - copy files into another folder, create new files with the same names using IDE, and replace the new files with the copied versions. It does the trick.

P.S. I grepped `.idea` folder and found no project file like `CMakeLists.txt` to edit manually. There are numerous entries in the `.idea/workspace.xml` file, but I am not sure how to generate proper entries by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I’m as surprised as many that there is no ‘import file’ or ‘add file’ option in Pycharm. I ended up just opening the file in the project, right clicking in the Project File pane on a file and opened that file in explorer to confirm the path to the project and then just used ‘Save As’ on the file I wanted to add and saved in the project folder.